# enqueue_stylesheet but it is not working on wordpress theme development

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, php-enqueue

i have recently download a theme and try to convert it into wordpress theme.

now i got stuck in error i am trying to enqueue my style sheet script into theme and its not working.

this is my header where i use wp_head() tag to hook my enqueue function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Document Title
    ============================================= -->
  <title>Index Template</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" /> -->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

this is my load style sheet function code and add_action function is use to hook the function to header

```
function ft_loadScripts()
{
    wp_register_style( 'ft_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ft_style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','ft_loadScripts' );
```

This is my main style sheet created for theme it is loacated in theme folder
in this style sheet i use only body backgound color to test the code .

```
/*
Theme Name: Firstweb
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/Firstweb/
Author:John don
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: Our default theme for 2020 is designed to take full advantage of the flexibility of the block editor. Organizations and businesses have the ability to create dynamic landing pages with endless layouts using the group and column blocks. The centered content column and fine-tuned typography also makes it perfect for traditional blogs. Complete editor styles give you a good idea of what your content will look like, even before you publish. You can give your site a personal touch by changing the background colors and the accent color in the Customizer. The colors of all elements on your site are automatically calculated based on the colors you pick, ensuring a high, accessible color contrast for your visitors.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: Firstweb
*/

body{
    background-color: black;
}
```

This my folder structure

[image]

In assets folder

[image]

This is how my theme look like

[image]

but i don't know why its not working. i also check in developer tool there is no error of style sheet in console but still the style sheet in not working at all

somebody plz help me with this
Thank You in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] - images of code are not allowed, you question must include the code itself. You can [edit] your question to include more information, but in this case the problem is that you're not telling it what stylesheet to load. Please review the documentation for enqueueing stylesheets to see what you need to do.

Comment: Could you include the HTML Wordpress outputs as well as an overview of the folder structure? I can’t find any fault in the code you provided and it works perfectly for me when trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FMJansen i edit my question and add folder structure and browser overview

Comment: The problem is still the same as I said in my comment - you are not including the stylesheet to be loaded!

Comment: @FluffyKitten actully i am new in wordpress i really didn't get what you are trying to say. So sorry for that can you give any example or can be more elaborate it

Comment: Is your stylesheet called "style.css" exactly (i.e. not "styles.scss" or something else) - we can't see the extensions in your images.

Comment: yes its directly in the theme folder as you can see in folder structure and its name as style.css

Comment: We can't see the extensions in your image so I wanted to be sure it wasn't called .scss or .less (or something totally unrelated to CSS!). Try add this to your `ft_loadScripts` function: `var_dump(get_stylesheet_uri()); die():` and see what it outputs (or it it outputs anything)

Comment: nothing happen and nothing change
by the way what this code is going to do ?

Comment: If you copied that *exactly* and nothing, changed then either the file this code is in isn't getting included, or you are accessing an old page from cache. There was a typo in that line so it should have thrown an error - the typo was unintentional, but its actually achieved the same result. Not sure why it wouldn't be picking up your functions.php so the more likely cause is caching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221023/discussion-between-mehran-ali-and-fluffykitten).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the code snippets should all work fine. However, it looks like your `functions.php` is called `function.php` (without the ‘s’), causing Wordpress to ignore the file. Hopefully renaming the file fixes your issue!

Comment: Thank you so much actully i use function.php but its functions.php now its working fine